# Query Json Objects using Hazelcast SqlPredicate

Tags: java, hazelcast

I'm using hazelcast in memory in my application.

Can anyone please explain how to query JSON objects using hazelcast..

map(String, new(HazelcastJsonValue());

In the value i'm storing entire JSON.

Storing JSON one by one in value:-

```
{"id":"01","name":"abc"}   

{"id":"02","name":" data"} 

{"id":"03","name":"abc"}
```

query:- name='abc'

Selecting based on the name

query:- name='abc'

Expecting output:-

```
{"id":"01","name":"abc"}  

{"id":"03","name":"abc"}
```

how to do this using hazelcast?

Thank you.

Comment: If this doesn't give guidance, https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/4.0.2/manual/html-single/index.html#querying-json-strings, can you post your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [link](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/4.0.2/manual/html-single/index.html#querying-json-strings) (sent by @Neil) is good. In your case, it will look like this:

```
HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();

String item1 = "{\"id\":\"01\",\"name\":\"abc\"}";
String item2 = "{\"id\":\"02\",\"name\":\" data\"}";
String item3 = "{\"id\":\"03\",\"name\":\"abc\"}";

IMap<String, HazelcastJsonValue> map = instance.getMap("jsonValues");

map.put("1", new HazelcastJsonValue(item1));
map.put("2", new HazelcastJsonValue(item2));
map.put("3", new HazelcastJsonValue(item3));

Collection<HazelcastJsonValue> selected = map.values(Predicates.equal("name", "abc"));
System.out.println(selected);
```

Comment: Thanks for ur time Rafal and Neil